# Multiple Tableviews inside Collection-view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on **Multiple Tableviews inside Collection-view**. And I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/mchirico/50cdb07d20b1b0f73d7c) article. But inside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method I am getting following error.

> Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'lblLab'
>   Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'lblLab'
>   Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'lblMedicine'

I have already created the separate classes for all the three tableview cells in which all the three labels are already mentioned.

Below is my code for the same which is written inside collection-view cell class.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell;
    if tableView == tableLAB {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labCell", for: indexPath) as! LabTableCell;
        cell.lblLab!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
    } else if tableView == tableDIAGNOSIS {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diagnosisCell", for: indexPath) as! DiagnosisTableCell;
        cell.lblDiagnosis!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
    } else if tableView == tableMEDICINE {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "medicineCell", for: indexPath) as! MedicineTableCell;
        cell.lblMedicine!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == tableLAB {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labCell", for: indexPath) as! LabTableCell;
        cell.lblLab!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
         return cell;
    } else if tableView == tableDIAGNOSIS {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diagnosisCell", for: indexPath) as! DiagnosisTableCell;
        cell.lblDiagnosis!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
         return cell;
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "medicineCell", for: indexPath) as! MedicineTableCell;
        cell.lblMedicine!.text = arr1[indexPath.row];
         return cell;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are trying to force cast an object initialised through parent class into a child class, this is not possible, what you can do is make sure that you have conditional operators for all cases i.e

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableview == a){
    //This is a conditional statement
    }
    else if(tableview == b){
    //This is a conditional statement
    }
    else{
    //This is a conditional statement
    }

    //no need to return anything here as your conditional operators are handling all return //cases
    }
```

and in each of the conditional statement, declare and initialise your unique cell type and return it eg.

```
let cell : CellType = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellType", for: indexPath) as! CellType;
return cell;
```